# Is there any study about using DMRG to simulate two spin chains coupled at only several sites on each chain?

Tags: condensed-matter, simulations, spin-models, spin-chains, tensor-network

Is there any study about the DMRG simulation of such kind of systems?

[image: One-Site coupling]

or

[image: Two-Site Coupling]

Each blue site is a spin, for example. Only one or several spins on each chain are coupled.

Comment: Are you looking for sth specific? In order to simulate such systems with DMRG a number of ways come to mind (e.g. thinking of this as a 1D system - like a ladder with only 1 or 2 rungs - or using some method based on trees).  I'm not sure which of those have been done.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Thank you for the info! I have searched the tree network and there's already quite a bit of research on it! This kind of configuration just pops into my mind when I thinking about the spin-boson model.

Comment: The other option is to just block the two rows, then you have a 1D system.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Would that be less efficient? If the state of the chains is compressed into an MPS (which is suitable for 1-D systems), the MPS will have nearest-neighbor sites from the upper chain and the low chain, although those two sites aren't coupled. Site N and site N+2 are coupled but they are separated by a site from the other chain. Will this scheme cause any problems?